# How should i structure my external urls to protect my federation gateway

Tags: security, url, identityserver4

I have not previously put much thought into what the externally facing URL's of my services and apps and sites should be.

However, we are currently implementing a new single sign on architecture with a landing page, utilising OAuth and Open ID Connect. To achieve this, we are using IdentityServer4 with a federation gateway, an internal identity provider linked to out Active directory and an identity provider for a database for one of our existing apps. The identity provider for our existing app already exists with an external URL but none of the others are created yet. This means that externally I now have to create 3 new URLs

1. for the landing page site we are protecting.
2. The federation gateway
3. The identity provider for my active directory.

Are there any known naming conventions for the federation gateway and ad identity provider in order to not leave them vulnerable to attack from external sources, or am I worrying about nothing.

For example, if I use

www.[domain].com/federationGateway

www.[domain].com/ADIdentityProvider

Am I leaving myself open for someone finding these addresses, thinking "hang on that’s a link to their AD, or that’s their federated gateway" then bombarding them with a DDoS attack and bringing down my single sign on architecture.

Any guidance that anyone can give me would be gratefully appreciated. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should never allow directories to be publicly accessed if you don't want anyone to find them. You can protect them by adding a login to access them (I'm not sure if you've done this?).

In regards to your concerns about DDOS attacks, you have nothing to worry about. DDOS attacks affect the whole domain, not just a subdirectory. For example, someone that DDOS'ed www.domain.com/RandomPath/Stuff would bring down all of www.domain.com, not just the subdirectory. If you are worried about DDOS attacks, you can either buy a "stronger" server or install software to prevent against DDOSing.

To sum it up, you don't have much to worry about. Unless you are being specifically targeted, nobody will find your federation or AD directories. DDOSing will most likely not be a problem for you unless someone with a lot of resources starts to DDOS you.